# Error: Failed to create scenario runner while using examples

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, bdd

I am using Examples to enter the email  but when I run the junit runner file it gives me the error:

```
"  Failed to create scenario runner"
```

My *Junit* runner code:

```
package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.Options;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Options(features="Features",glue={"stepdefinition"})


public class GmailRunner {

}
```

Here is my *feature* file:

```
    Feature: Smoke test of Gmail


@GmailSignin
  Scenario Outline: Click on Sign in
    Given Open chrome 
    When  I go to gmail and  click on Sign in
    When I enter "<emailid>" 
    Then I  click on next

Examples:
    | emailid |
    | sarveshsingh.03 |
```

I am using **Cucumber-junit-1.1.2** and **junit-4.11**

Please help

Comment: could you try upgrading your cucumber-junit ?

Comment: Sir i tried that after reading some solutions with 3.0.2 but it's not working with that as well

Comment: check your pom.xml and see the dependencies are correct or not

Comment: Ok sir but i am using java project do I have to add dependency in java project as well???

Comment: yes, refer this - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_junit_runner.htm

Comment: sir I have a java project I am not able to see the pom.xml file

Comment: Sir I added the dependencies thanks for that the error got removed but now I am facing a new error while running my runner file that is "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(Ljava/util/Properties;" Please help @prany

Comment: @SarveshSingh  What is the cucumber version u have decided to use finally?  Are you using Maven? If so, add the pom.xml. If not add a list of java dependeencies you have added. I copied the code and ran it on version 3.0.2 and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Grasshopper sir for what you have used the version 3.0..2 please let me know I will try the same

Comment: @SarveshSingh Added runner and pom. Also no need to address everyone by 'sir', name will do just fine. Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to add the pom and runner file It saying that you have too muh code

Comment: @SarveshSingh Do u have a maven project? Or simple java project?

Comment: @Grasshopper I have a maven project and I have tried to change my version to 3.0.2 but then my pom gives the error

Comment: @SarveshSingh Remove the existing dependencies portion and add the one I added in the answer

Comment: @Grasshopper It still gives me the same error No such method error

Comment: @SarveshSingh Can  u add the full stacktrace error to the question? Are u using the runner that i added?

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(Ljava/util/Properties;[Ljava/lang/String;)V

Comment: yes I used your runner as well

Answer (score 0):

**@Options** is deprecated in cucumber-junit-1.1.2 . You should use @CucumberOptions and provide tag names inside it .

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "relative/path/to/your/featureFile.feature",
        tags = "@GmailSignin",
        format = { "pretty",
        "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty",
        "rerun:target/rerun.txt",
        "json:target/cucumber1.json" })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the pom dependencies... If you are using plain java download these versions from maven repository and include them.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>tag-expressions</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This is the runner class. CHange the features and glue value to suit your enviroment.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features/gmail.feature",glue={"stepdef"}, dryRun=false)
public class GmailRunner {

}
```